# Table cell into view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview that displays a newsfeed with parser rss. I want the top cell to be displayed in another view controller. Imagine it as if you have a newsfeed and you want to post the latest news on the homepage. How do i solve this?!
I have not found anything alike on the web and therefor asking this question.

Note that this code is working fine for gathering the rss feed. I want to ''copy'' the first cell and display it on the homepage.

```
@interface TableViewController () {
NSXMLParser *parser;
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSMutableDictionary *item;
NSMutableString *title;
NSMutableString *link;
NSString *element;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://feedity.com/dinskolmat-    se/VFJSUFJa.rss"];
                            //http://clownfish.skolpytt.appspot.com/ostra-real/rss
                            //https://feedity.com/dinskolmat-se/VFJSUFJa.rss"];

parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
[self.view     addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader";
UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (headerView == nil){
    [NSException raise:@"headerView == nil.." format:@"No cells with matching CellIdentifier loaded from your storyboard"];
}
return headerView;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 90.0f;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return feeds.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
return cell;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
element = elementName;
if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
    [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [title appendString:string];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [link appendString:string];
}
}


-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setURL:string];
}
}
- (IBAction)homebutton:(id)sender {

}
@end
```

Comment: Please paste your code into your question rather than linking to a screen shot. Also it is unclear what your *specific* question is - what isn't working in your code or what are you having trouble with.  Refer to the help a section for suggestions on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Maybe you have some design how it should looks like? It's a bit hard to understand which behavior do you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to copy a cell, at least a cell instance. The cell instances are managed by the table view. Moreover, there is nothing to copy, probably. You just want to display the same data twice or at 2 different places.

You should decouple your understanding of a view with that of a model. If you want to use a "cell" inside another view controller, tell that other (table)viewcontroller to use the same *kind* of cell, and once it requests it (after a reloadData for instance), fill that cell with the same model data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to copy the cell,instead try to get the data of that cell and make a custom view like a table cell and paste the data in that `custom view`. If I were you,I will make a `custom view` that looks like a table cell and will parse the data to that view.

Comment: There is no particular  tutorial for making custom view,as it depends on user requirements. You can add a rectangular UIview with the same dimensions as of your table cell.Then include the labels in that view.